# Applescript to bring a Terminal window to front

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a shell script which runs a long-running processes in a Terminal window.

I leave it running and work on other Terminal windows.

I'd like to be notified when the shell script finishes, by bringing its window
to front.

I have following code, which I wanted to run at the end of the shell script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        try
            set win to (!code to get current window!)
            perform action "AXRaise" of win
        end try
    end tell
  end tell
```

but I don't know how to get current window.

Comment: Does your window have a unique name? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173514/applescript-bring-window-to-foreground

Comment: @Tetsujin All my Terminal windows have generic name like `User - Directory - Shell type`. But I can give it a unique name. Will take a look at the link.

Comment: I found a few scripts similar - all seem easy to find the window by name. Couldn't see anything that would find it by number that was reliable.

Comment: Does the window have any unique content? This probably isn't the most efficient approach but if your terminal windows are sane then you could `set x to windows whose contents contains "unique string"` which will return a list, presumably with a single window item. Then `set index of item 1 of x to 1`. If the window has but a single tab it will make things easier (as then you can avoid having lists of lists) but you can also monkey around with the contents of `tabs of…`. Added bonus… you don't have to use ui scripting.

Comment: @Mockman What do you mean by `you don't have to use ui scripting` ?

Comment: You don't have to do the `AXRaise` bit. Instead `set index of window 2 to 1`.

Comment: @Mockman I did `set x to windows whose contents contains "unique string"` followed by `set index of item 1 of x to 1` after making sure my window contains `unique string`, but got error `163:210: execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get contents of window. (-1728)`

Comment: Tell the Terminal, not System Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set hw to windows whose contents contains "new-glasses"
    --> {window id 67 of application "Terminal"}
    
    set hw1 to item 1 of hw
    --> window id 67 of application "Terminal"
    
    set index of hw1 to 1
end tell
```

The above script presumes that only one window will contain the specified string and that it has but one tab. The first line gets a list with a single item — the matching window. The second line gets that specific window. The third line sets its index to 1 (i.e. makes it the front window). Dunno if it makes a difference but I'm running this on Sierra.

Comment: I just need to add `activate` after `tell application ...`. BTW, it works on Ventura.

Comment: One quick question, is it possible to print the content of the window in the above script ?

Comment: Try adding `print hw1 with print dialog`. There are a handful of print settings that you can apply. The print dialogue is optional. Alternatively, you could always do something directly with the contents, e.g. assign a variable, write to a text file, add to an app's document, etc… and then print that.